# TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined- Angular 5

Tags: angular5

I am trying to `splice` object from an array of list of object, passing an object index as the first argument `splice(index, 1)`, but it results in the following error:

> Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined.

Comment: ngOnInit() {
 this.Service.deleteIndex(res => {
   if (res > -1) {
    this.MypostList.splice(res, 1);
   }
}

Comment: You should debug your code and find out why the object you are using is undefined. Include your codes in question maybe someone could help.

Comment: Please, put your code in the question content so we can see the context. By the way, what do you mean by "array of list of object"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**this.MypostList** is somehow evaluated empty in your code. So splice could not be executed on the empty object. Please put the code where you tried to evaluate this.MypostList

Comment: yes. you are right.i got solution. i  put the code where i evaluate this.MypostList.